# docker httpd/Apache - adding new node,js modules

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, docker, apache

I'm new to the web developing stuff and currently watching on udemy a 70h course.
I like to practice new learned stuff in real world applications. Therefore I've setted up an httpd container (https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) with a bootstrap template in it (https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2)

My question: how do I add new node.js modules to this template? I want to add a module to connect the website to my postgres database.
The volume I made for the httpd container is as follows: `/usr/local/apache2/sb/src/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/`
In this directory I have installed the postgres module via npm and wrote a simple javascript code in index.js. If I call index.js via `node index.js` from the terminal it works fine. If I try to call it from the website it doesnt work. I know I missed something important to get this module work but I can't figure it out.

**Edit**
It was a really simple example of using extern modules in node.js shown in udemy. I've tried to use this example in my website.

index.js

```
var superhero = require('superheroes');
var hero = superhero.random();

    function testCall(){
        // alert("just a test!");
        alert(hero);
    }
```

In index.html I call the "testCall" function as follows

```
<body id="page-top" onload="testCall()">
```

This part works well, If I put a simple string as alert, for instance "alert("just a test!");"

I want to build a dashboard to display some values stored in postgres

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what the job of Apache httpd is. You seem to have it working outside of the container, can you share a little bit more detail on how the index.js and the bootstrap template play together there?

Comment: Hi @criztovyl I definitely misunderstood something. I'm comfortable with javascript programming and therefore preferred js instead of php. I did some research the last few minutes. Am I right if I'm simplifying it to: Apache uses php and nodejs uses javascript for backend development? Apache and Node.js can both serve web content?

Comment: As a simplification it works, yes.

Comment: It seems what you want to do is to display data from a database in the template you linked, correct? Please share a little bit more detail what your index.js currently does, that will help understanding where you stand, how to improve your question, and provide an answer. :)

Comment: As it seems to be an example you are working on, simply consider sharing the "whole" index.js. if it's simple enough, put it to the answer, otherwise consider a pastebin.

Comment: Thanks for your time @criztovyl It was a really simple example of using extern modules in node.js shown in udemy. I've tried to use this example in my website.

index.js
var superhero = require('superheroes');
var hero = superhero.random();

function testCall(){
    // alert("just a test!");
    alert(hero);
}

In index.html I call the "testCall" function as follows
<body id="page-top" onload="testCall()">
This part works well If I put a simple string as alert, for instance "alert("just a test!");"

You are right. I want to build a dashboard to monitor some values from the DB

Comment: the comment section isn't for formatting code stuff :D
I've edited my origin post with the node.js

Comment: Can you provide what your udemy course is about specifically, maybe a linkt to it? It seems you are missing the understanding where, among server and client, your different parts of the code are (supposed to be) running.

Comment: ofc. https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/. maybe I should get through the course stuff before asking question who probably gets answered in it.